# Exception in thread “main” java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea

```
package javax.swing;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.security.AccessController;
import javax.accessibility.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.RootPaneUI;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import sun.awt.AWTAccessor;
import sun.security.action.GetBooleanAction;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JRootPane extends JComponent implements Accessible {

    private static final String uiClassID = "RootPaneUI";


    public static final int COLOR_CHOOSER_DIALOG = 5;


    public static final int FILE_CHOOSER_DIALOG = 6;


    public static final int QUESTION_DIALOG = 7;


    public static final int WARNING_DIALOG = 8;

    private int windowDecorationStyle;


    protected JMenuBar menuBar;

    /** The content pane. */
    protected Container contentPane;

    /** The layered pane that manages the menu bar and content pane. */
    protected JLayeredPane layeredPane;

    protected Component glassPane;

    protected JButton defaultButton;

    boolean useTrueDoubleBuffering = true;

    static {
        LOG_DISABLE_TRUE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING =
            AccessController.doPrivileged(new GetBooleanAction(
                                   "swing.logDoubleBufferingDisable"));
        IGNORE_DISABLE_TRUE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING =
            AccessController.doPrivileged(new GetBooleanAction(
                                   "swing.ignoreDoubleBufferingDisable"));
    }


    public JRootPane() {
        setGlassPane(createGlassPane());
        setLayeredPane(createLayeredPane());
        setContentPane(createContentPane());
        setLayout(createRootLayout());
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        updateUI();
    }


    public void setDoubleBuffered(boolean aFlag) {
        if (isDoubleBuffered() != aFlag) {
            super.setDoubleBuffered(aFlag);
            RepaintManager.currentManager(this).doubleBufferingChanged(this);
        }
    }


    public int getWindowDecorationStyle() {
        return windowDecorationStyle;
    }


    public void setWindowDecorationStyle(int windowDecorationStyle) {
        if (windowDecorationStyle < 0 ||
                  windowDecorationStyle > WARNING_DIALOG) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid decoration style");
        }
        int oldWindowDecorationStyle = getWindowDecorationStyle();
        this.windowDecorationStyle = windowDecorationStyle;
        firePropertyChange("windowDecorationStyle",
                            oldWindowDecorationStyle,
                            windowDecorationStyle);
    }


    public RootPaneUI getUI() {
        return (RootPaneUI)ui;
    }


    public void setUI(RootPaneUI ui) {
        super.setUI(ui);
    }



    public void updateUI() {
        setUI((RootPaneUI)UIManager.getUI(this));
    }



    public String getUIClassID() {
        return uiClassID;
    }


    protected JLayeredPane createLayeredPane() {
        JLayeredPane p = new JLayeredPane();
        p.setName(this.getName()+".layeredPane");
        return p;
    }


    protected Container createContentPane() {
        JComponent c = new JPanel();
        c.setName(this.getName()+".contentPane");
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout() {

            public void addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraints) {
                if (constraints == null) {
                    constraints = BorderLayout.CENTER;
                }
                super.addLayoutComponent(comp, constraints);
            }
        });
        return c;
    }


    protected Component createGlassPane() {
        JComponent c = new JPanel();
        c.setName(this.getName()+".glassPane");
        c.setVisible(false);
        ((JPanel)c).setOpaque(false);
        return c;
    }


    protected LayoutManager createRootLayout() {
        return new RootLayout();
    }


    public void setJMenuBar(JMenuBar menu) {
        if(menuBar != null && menuBar.getParent() == layeredPane)
            layeredPane.remove(menuBar);
        menuBar = menu;

        if(menuBar != null)
            layeredPane.add(menuBar, JLayeredPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
    }


    @Deprecated
    public void setMenuBar(JMenuBar menu){
        if(menuBar != null && menuBar.getParent() == layeredPane)
            layeredPane.remove(menuBar);
        menuBar = menu;

        if(menuBar != null)
            layeredPane.add(menuBar, JLayeredPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
    }


    public JMenuBar getJMenuBar() { return menuBar; }


    @Deprecated
    public JMenuBar getMenuBar() { return menuBar; }


    public void setContentPane(Container content) {
        if(content == null)
            throw new IllegalComponentStateException("contentPane cannot be set to null.");
        if(contentPane != null && contentPane.getParent() == layeredPane)
            layeredPane.remove(contentPane);
        contentPane = content;

        layeredPane.add(contentPane, JLayeredPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
    }


    public Container getContentPane() { return contentPane; }


    public void setLayeredPane(JLayeredPane layered) {
        if(layered == null)
            throw new IllegalComponentStateException("layeredPane cannot be set to null.");
        if(layeredPane != null && layeredPane.getParent() == this)
            this.remove(layeredPane);
        layeredPane = layered;

        this.add(layeredPane, -1);
    }

    public JLayeredPane getLayeredPane() { return layeredPane; }


    public void setGlassPane(Component glass) {
        if (glass == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("glassPane cannot be set to null.");
        }

        AWTAccessor.getComponentAccessor().setMixingCutoutShape(glass,
                new Rectangle());

        boolean visible = false;
        if (glassPane != null && glassPane.getParent() == this) {
            this.remove(glassPane);
            visible = glassPane.isVisible();
        }

        glass.setVisible(visible);
        glassPane = glass;
        this.add(glassPane, 0);
        if (visible) {
            repaint();
        }
    }


    public Component getGlassPane() {
        return glassPane;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isValidateRoot() {
        return true;
    }


    public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() {
        return !glassPane.isVisible();
    }


    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        enableEvents(AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
    }


    public void removeNotify() {
        super.removeNotify();
    }



    public void setDefaultButton(JButton defaultButton) {
        JButton oldDefault = this.defaultButton;

        if (oldDefault != defaultButton) {
            this.defaultButton = defaultButton;

            if (oldDefault != null) {
                oldDefault.repaint();
            }
            if (defaultButton != null) {
                defaultButton.repaint();
            }
        }

        firePropertyChange("defaultButton", oldDefault, defaultButton);
    }


    public JButton getDefaultButton() {
        return defaultButton;
    }

    final void setUseTrueDoubleBuffering(boolean useTrueDoubleBuffering) {
        this.useTrueDoubleBuffering = useTrueDoubleBuffering;
    }

    final boolean getUseTrueDoubleBuffering() {
        return useTrueDoubleBuffering;
    }

    final void disableTrueDoubleBuffering() {
        if (useTrueDoubleBuffering) {
            if (!IGNORE_DISABLE_TRUE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING) {
                if (LOG_DISABLE_TRUE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING) {
                    System.out.println("Disabling true double buffering for " +
                                       this);
                    Thread.dumpStack();
                }
                useTrueDoubleBuffering = false;
                RepaintManager.currentManager(this).
                        doubleBufferingChanged(this);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    static class DefaultAction extends AbstractAction {
        JButton owner;
        JRootPane root;
        boolean press;
        DefaultAction(JRootPane root, boolean press) {
            this.root = root;
            this.press = press;
        }
        public void setOwner(JButton owner) {
            this.owner = owner;
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (owner != null && SwingUtilities.getRootPane(owner) == root) {
                ButtonModel model = owner.getModel();
                if (press) {
                    model.setArmed(true);
                    model.setPressed(true);
                } else {
                    model.setPressed(false);
                }
            }
        }
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return owner.getModel().isEnabled();
        }
    }



    protected void addImpl(Component comp, Object constraints, int index) {
        super.addImpl(comp, constraints, index);

        if(glassPane != null
            && glassPane.getParent() == this
            && getComponent(0) != glassPane) {
            add(glassPane, 0);
        }
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    protected class RootLayout implements LayoutManager2, Serializable
    {

        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            Dimension rd, mbd;
            Insets i = getInsets();

            if(contentPane != null) {
                rd = contentPane.getPreferredSize();
            } else {
                rd = parent.getSize();
            }
            if(menuBar != null && menuBar.isVisible()) {
                mbd = menuBar.getPreferredSize();
            } else {
                mbd = new Dimension(0, 0);
            }
            return new Dimension(Math.max(rd.width, mbd.width) + i.left + i.right,
                                        rd.height + mbd.height + i.top + i.bottom);
        }


        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            Dimension rd, mbd;
            Insets i = getInsets();
            if(contentPane != null) {
                rd = contentPane.getMinimumSize();
            } else {
                rd = parent.getSize();
            }
            if(menuBar != null && menuBar.isVisible()) {
                mbd = menuBar.getMinimumSize();
            } else {
                mbd = new Dimension(0, 0);
            }
            return new Dimension(Math.max(rd.width, mbd.width) + i.left + i.right,
                        rd.height + mbd.height + i.top + i.bottom);
        }


        public Dimension maximumLayoutSize(Container target) {
            Dimension rd, mbd;
            Insets i = getInsets();
            if(menuBar != null && menuBar.isVisible()) {
                mbd = menuBar.getMaximumSize();
            } else {
                mbd = new Dimension(0, 0);
            }
            if(contentPane != null) {
                rd = contentPane.getMaximumSize();
            } else {
                // This is silly, but should stop an overflow error
                rd = new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                        Integer.MAX_VALUE - i.top - i.bottom - mbd.height - 1);
            }
            return new Dimension(Math.min(rd.width, mbd.width) + i.left + i.right,
                                         rd.height + mbd.height + i.top + i.bottom);
        }


        public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
            Rectangle b = parent.getBounds();
            Insets i = getInsets();
            int contentY = 0;
            int w = b.width - i.right - i.left;
            int h = b.height - i.top - i.bottom;

            if(layeredPane != null) {
                layeredPane.setBounds(i.left, i.top, w, h);
            }
            if(glassPane != null) {
                glassPane.setBounds(i.left, i.top, w, h);
            }
            // Note: This is laying out the children in the layeredPane,
            // technically, these are not our children.
            if(menuBar != null && menuBar.isVisible()) {
                Dimension mbd = menuBar.getPreferredSize();
                menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, w, mbd.height);
                contentY += mbd.height;
            }
            if(contentPane != null) {
                contentPane.setBounds(0, contentY, w, h - contentY);
            }
        }

        public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {}
        public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {}
        public void addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraints) {}
        public float getLayoutAlignmentX(Container target) { return 0.0f; }
        public float getLayoutAlignmentY(Container target) { return 0.0f; }
        public void invalidateLayout(Container target) {}
    }


    protected String paramString() {
        return super.paramString();
    }

/////////////////
// Accessibility support
////////////////


    public AccessibleContext getAccessibleContext() {
        if (accessibleContext == null) {
            accessibleContext = new AccessibleJRootPane();
        }
        return accessibleContext;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    protected class AccessibleJRootPane extends AccessibleJComponent {

        public AccessibleRole getAccessibleRole() {
            return AccessibleRole.ROOT_PANE;
        }


        public int getAccessibleChildrenCount() {
            return super.getAccessibleChildrenCount();
        }


        public Accessible getAccessibleChild(int i) {
            return super.getAccessibleChild(i);
        }
    } // inner class AccessibleJRootPane
}
```

[I'm newby in Java, i'm googled all descussions about my problem. They are doesn't help me. Hope for your help. Sorry for my English. :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMJl8.png)

I'm newby in Java, i'm googled all descussions about my problem. They are doesn't help me. Hope for your help. Sorry for my English. :)

This exception was come in time building project, but intellij IDEA didn't mark any code strings.

All problem functions:

1 function (at javax.swing.JRootPane.setContentPane(JRootPane.java:621))

```
public void setContentPane(Container content) {
        if(content == null)
            throw new IllegalComponentStateException("contentPane cannot be set to null.");
        if(contentPane != null && contentPane.getParent() == layeredPane)
            layeredPane.remove(contentPane);
        contentPane = content;

        layeredPane.add(contentPane, JLayeredPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
    }
```

2 function (at javax.swing.JFrame.setContentPane(JFrame.java:698))

```
public void setContentPane(Container contentPane) {
        getRootPane().setContentPane(contentPane);
    }
```

3 function (at com.company.AuthorizationGUI.(AuthorizationGUI.java:21))

```
 AuthorizationGUI() {
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        Dimension s = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int width = 300, height = 200;
        int X = (s.width - width) / 2;
        int Y = (s.height - height) / 2;
        setBounds(X, Y, width, height);

        errorInput.setVisible(false);
        enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                enter();
            }
        });
        registration.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                registration();
            }
        });
```

4 function (at com.company.Client.connect(Client.java:42))

```
 private void connect() {
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1000);
            coos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            cois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            new AuthorizationGUI();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

5 function (at com.company.Client.(Client.java:21))

```
private Client() {
        connect();
    }
```

6 function (at com.company.Client.getInstance(Client.java:30))

```
public static Client getInstance() {
        Client localInstance = instance;
        if (localInstance == null) {
            synchronized (Client.class) {
                localInstance = instance;
                if (localInstance == null) {
                    instance = localInstance = new Client();
                }
            }
        }
        return localInstance;
    }
```

7 function (at com.company.Client.main(Client.java:17))

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Client.getInstance();
    }
```

Comment: try to narrow down your problem to the simplest implementation that still fails. You should also point out exactly where your code fails and what you have tried to fix it.

Comment: 'public void setContentPane(Container content) {
        if(content == null)
            throw new IllegalComponentStateException("contentPane cannot be set to null.");
        if(contentPane != null && contentPane.getParent() == layeredPane)
            layeredPane.remove(contentPane);
        contentPane = content;

        layeredPane.add(contentPane, JLayeredPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
    }'

Comment: Yeah, not in a comment - edit your main question.

Comment: @Alan I did it.

Answer (score 0):

One good solution for you. Don't use the Swing library in Java, it's too old technology. The better way is definitely JavaFX.
[Some tutorials here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm)